# Como puedo saber que replica en especifico reponde a un servicio LoadBalancer en kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Hola tengo montado un deployment de kubernetes que usa un servico tipo LoadBalancer y quisiera saber si existe una forma de saber cual replica responde cada ves que se llama el servicio.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no he encontrado una manera concisa de realizar la tarea que has planteado con el uso de `kubectl`. El approach que se me ocurrió quizás te resulte útil. Hice uso de los **logs referenciados al deployment** y no al pod concreto, mediante esta técnica vas a poder visualizar todos los logs de los pods de dicho deployment y de esta manera trackear cual se está llamando por el servicio LoadBalancer.

El comando es el siguiente:

`kubectl logs deployment/<nombre del deployment> -n <nombre del namespace>`

> Puede que no necesites indicar el namespace con la flag -n si tu deployment se encuentra en el namespace default

en caso de que desees mantenerte a la escucha activa a nuevos eventos que puedan llegar a tus pods deberás agregar la flag -f:

`kubectl logs -f deployment/<nombre del deployment> -n <nombre del namespace>`

Otra solución visualmente más intuitiva es [stern](https://github.com/stern/stern). Visualizarás los logs de cada pod con colores distintos y bien diferenciados.

Espero te sirva y si encontraste una solución a tu problema me gustaría conocerla.